# Flutter app shows an ad for no reason after release

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling

My flutter app shows this ad for no reason after release. How can I disable it?[image]

Comment: Do you have any ad in your app?

Comment: No, but wait how can I check if I have it?

Comment: Try checking all the pubs, seems like someone is injecting ads trough a pub if your app don't have ads

Comment: Ok, how can I detect which pub is doing it?

Comment: @ItzDavi hi do you have any solutions?

Comment: You should "isolate" every pub. You have to build the app in release and testing, removing one pub at time. By doing so you should be able to find the pub showing ads. Can you also post your pubspec.yaml so I can see the pub list ?

Comment: Thanks for your response, I was able to fix the issue, the package was Firebase in app messaging, it was sending ads for no reason, I just removed it and now the issue is solved. Appreciate for your help